# sql query inside if stage with exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to check if the id I want to insert into tableA exists in tableB into an if statement
Can I do something like this

```
  if new.id exists (select id from tableB where stat = '0' ) then
       some code here
  end if;
```

When I try this I get an error message, any thoughts?

Comment: ...and the *exact error message* is... ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually done with a trigger. A trigger function does the trick:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "trf_insert_tableA"() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  PERFORM * FROM "tableB" WHERE id = NEW.id AND stat = '0';
  IF FOUND THEN
    -- Any additional code to go here, optional
    RETURN NEW;
  ELSE
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER "tr_insert_tableA"
  BEFORE INSERT ON "tableA"
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE "trf_insert_tableA"();
```

A few notes:

- Identifiers in PostgreSQL are case-insensitive. PostgreSQL by default makes them lower-case. To maintain the case, use double-quotes. To make your life easy, use lower-case only.
- A [trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) needs a trigger function, this is always a two-step affair.
- In an `INSERT` trigger, you can use the `NEW` implicit parameter to access the column values that are attempted to be inserted. In the trigger function you can modify these values and those values are then inserted. This only works in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, obviously; `AFTER INSERT` triggers are used for side effects such as logging, auditing or cascading inserts to other tables.
- [The `PERFORM` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) is a special form of a `SELECT` statement to test for the presence of data; it does not return any data, but it does set the `FOUND` implicit parameter that you can use in a conditional statement.
- Depending on your logic, you may want the insert to succeed or to fail. `RETURN NEW` to make the insert succeed, `RETURN NULL` to make it fail.

After you defined the trigger, you can simply issue an `INSERT` statement: the trigger function is invoked automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it like this? I'm not very knowledgeable about PostgreSQL but this would work in T-SQL.

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable(ID)
    SELECT ID
    FROM TableB
    WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TargetTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
if exists (select 1 from tableB b where stat = '0' and b.id = new.id) then
     some code here
end if;
```